# Help with exercise package, all questions not showing up

Tags: exercises

This is part of code for creating a could of questions as part of a worksheet but I cannot understand why all the questions do not show up.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{newfile}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{tikz}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\usepackage[left=1.00cm, right=1.00cm, top=3.00cm, bottom=3.00cm]{geometry}


%start of book and exercise code
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newoutputstream{solutions}
\openoutputfile{\jobname.solutions}{solutions}
\newcounter{exblock}
\newcounter{exquestion}
\newcounter{exsubquestion}
\newlist{questionlist}{enumerate}{1}
\newlist{solutionlist}{enumerate}{1}
\newlist{subquestionlist}{enumerate*}{1}
\newlist{subsolutionlist}{enumerate*}{1}
\setlist[questionlist,solutionlist]{label=\arabic*.}
\setlist[subquestionlist,subsolutionlist]{label=(\alph*),itemjoin={},before=~}
\newcommand{\exheader}{%
\ifthenelse{\value{exblock}>0}{\addtostream{solutions} {\noexpand\end{solutionlist}}}{}%
    \refstepcounter{exblock}%
    \setcounter{exquestion}{0}%
    \section{Exercises}%
    \label{ex.\arabic{exblock}}%
    \addtostream{solutions}{\noexpand\paragraph{Exercises        \noexpand\ref{ex.\arabic{exblock}}, page \noexpand\pageref{ex.\arabic{exblock}}}}%
    \addtostream{solutions}{\noexpand\begin{solutionlist}}%
}
\newcommand{\printsolutions}{%
     \ifthenelse{\value{exblock}>0}{\addtostream{solutions} {\noexpand\end{solutionlist}}}{}%
    \closeoutputstream{solutions}%
    \input{\jobname.solutions}%
}
\newenvironment{exercises}[1][]{%
    \begin{questionlist}[start=\value{exquestion}+1, #1]%
}{%
    \end{questionlist}%
}
\newenvironment{exercisescol}[2][]{%
     \begin{multicols}{#2}%
     \begin{questionlist}[start=\value{exquestion}+1, #1]%
}{%
    \end{questionlist}%
    \end{multicols}%
}
\newcommand{\question}[2]{%
    \refstepcounter{exquestion}%
    \label{ex.\arabic{exblock}.\arabic{exquestion}}%
    \item #1%
    \addtostream{solutions} {\noexpand\item[\noexpand\ref{ex.\arabic{exblock}.\arabic{exquestion}}.] #2}%
}
\newenvironment{subquestions}[1][]{%
    \refstepcounter{exquestion}%
    \label{ex.\arabic{exblock}.\arabic{exquestion}}%
    \setcounter{exsubquestion}{0}%
    \addtostream{solutions} {\noexpand\item[\noexpand\ref{ex.\arabic{exblock}.\arabic{exquestion}}.]\noexpand\begin {subsolutionlist}}%
    \item #1%
    \begin{subquestionlist}%
}{%
    \end{subquestionlist}%
    \addtostream{solutions}{\noexpand\end{subsolutionlist}}
}
\newcommand{\subquestion}[2]{%
    \refstepcounter{exsubquestion}%
    \item #1%
    \addtostream{solutions}{\noexpand\item #2}%
 }


 \setlist*[questionlist]{font=\bfseries}
 \setlist*[solutionlist]{noitemsep,font=\bfseries}
 \setlist*[subquestionlist]{font=\bfseries}
 \setlist*[subsolutionlist]{noitemsep,font=\bfseries,itemjoin={\\},before={}}
 %end of book and exercise code


 \begin{document}

 So for example the number forty five thousand, two hundred and seventy three\\
 can be broken down as;\\

 \vspace{1cm}

 \begin{table}[htp!]
       \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
  
            \hline
            Millions & hundred thousand & ten thousand & thousand & hundred & tens  & units\\
            \hline
            1,000,000 & 100,000 & 10,000 & 1,000 & 100 & 10 & 1\\      
            \hline
            0 & 0 & 4 & 5 & 2 & 7 & 3\\
            \hline
  
      \end{tabular}
\end{table}    

\vspace{1cm}

so in figures the number forty five thousand, two hundred and seventy three will be\\
45,273\\



\exheader
Write the following numbers in figures
\begin{exercisescol}[noitemsep]{2}
    \question{Five thousand, one hundred and three}
    \question{Three hundred tousand, seven hundred and nighty one}
    \question{two and a half million}
    \question{one million, seven hundred and two thousand, two hundred and four}
\end{exercisescol}

\end{document}
```

Any help would be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some corrections to `\question` and guessing that the first optional parameter is the solution to be listed.

[image: c]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{newfile}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{tikz}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\usepackage[left=1.00cm, right=1.00cm, top=3.00cm, bottom=3.00cm]{geometry}


%start of book and exercise code
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newoutputstream{solutions}
\openoutputfile{\jobname.solutions}{solutions}
\newcounter{exblock}
\newcounter{exquestion}
\newcounter{exsubquestion}
\newlist{questionlist}{enumerate}{1}
\newlist{solutionlist}{enumerate}{1}
\newlist{subquestionlist}{enumerate*}{1}
\newlist{subsolutionlist}{enumerate*}{1}
\setlist[questionlist,solutionlist]{label=\arabic*.}
\setlist[subquestionlist,subsolutionlist]{label=(\alph*),itemjoin={},before=~}
\newcommand{\exheader}{%
    \ifthenelse{\value{exblock}>0}{\addtostream{solutions} {\noexpand\end{solutionlist}}}{}%
\refstepcounter{exblock}%
\setcounter{exquestion}{0}%
\section{Exercises}%
\label{ex.\arabic{exblock}}%
\addtostream{solutions}{\noexpand\paragraph{Exercises        \noexpand\ref{ex.\arabic{exblock}}, page \noexpand\pageref{ex.\arabic{exblock}}}}%
\addtostream{solutions}{\noexpand\begin{solutionlist}}%
}
\newcommand{\printsolutions}{%
    \ifthenelse{\value{exblock}>0}{\addtostream{solutions} {\noexpand\end{solutionlist}}}{}%
\closeoutputstream{solutions}%
\input{\jobname.solutions}%
}
\newenvironment{exercises}[1][]{%
\begin{questionlist}[start=\value{exquestion}+1, #1]%
}{%
\end{questionlist}%
}
\newenvironment{exercisescol}[2][]{%
\begin{multicols}{#2}%
    \begin{questionlist}[start=\value{exquestion}+1, #1]%
    }{%
    \end{questionlist}%
\end{multicols}%
}


\newcommand{\question}[2][]{% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\refstepcounter{exquestion}%
\label{ex.\arabic{exblock}.\arabic{exquestion}}%
\item #2%%changed <<<<
\addtostream{solutions} {\noexpand\item[\noexpand\ref{ex.\arabic{exblock}.\arabic{exquestion}}.] #1}%%changed <<<<
}


\newenvironment{subquestions}[1][]{%
\refstepcounter{exquestion}%
\label{ex.\arabic{exblock}.\arabic{exquestion}}%
\setcounter{exsubquestion}{0}%
\addtostream{solutions} {\noexpand\item[\noexpand\ref{ex.\arabic{exblock}.\arabic{exquestion}}.]\noexpand\begin {subsolutionlist}}%
\item #1%
\begin{subquestionlist}%
}{%
\end{subquestionlist}%
\addtostream{solutions}{\noexpand\end{subsolutionlist}}
}
\newcommand{\subquestion}[2]{%
\refstepcounter{exsubquestion}%
\item #1%
\addtostream{solutions}{\noexpand\item #2}%
}


\setlist*[questionlist]{font=\bfseries}
\setlist*[solutionlist]{noitemsep,font=\bfseries}
\setlist*[subquestionlist]{font=\bfseries}
\setlist*[subsolutionlist]{noitemsep,font=\bfseries,itemjoin={\\},before={}}
%end of book and exercise code


\begin{document}

So for example the number forty five thousand, two hundred and seventy three\\
can be broken down as;\\

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{table}[htp!]
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    
    \hline
    Millions & hundred thousand & ten thousand & thousand & hundred & tens  & units\\
    \hline
    1,000,000 & 100,000 & 10,000 & 1,000 & 100 & 10 & 1\\      
    \hline
    0 & 0 & 4 & 5 & 2 & 7 & 3\\
    \hline
    
\end{tabular}
\end{table}    

\vspace{1cm}

so in figures the number forty five thousand, two hundred and seventy three will be\\
45,273\\

\exheader
Write the following numbers in figures
\begin{exercisescol}[noitemsep]{2}
\question[5,103]{Five thousand, one hundred and three}
\question[370,091]{Three hundred thousand, seven hundred and ninety one}
\question[2,500,000]{Two and a half million}
\question[1,702,204]{One million, seven hundred and two thousand, two hundred and four}
\end{exercisescol}

\printsolutions % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, my error was not providing the solution, how stupid of me.